# Error Message- Failed with: success/error was not called

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

```
Parse.Cloud.job("JobSchedule", function(request, response) {

    var Group = Parse.Object.extend("Group");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Group);
    query.equalTo("JobScheduled", true);
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
                var created = new Date(results[i].createdAt);
                var current = new Date();
                var timeDiff = Math.abs(current.getTime() - created.getTime());
                var horsDiff = timeDiff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
                if (horsDiff >= parseInt(results[i].get("JobHours"))) {
                    results[i].set("JobScheduled", false);
                    results[i].set("GroupType", "Private");
                    results[i].set("JobHours", 0);
                    results[i].save();

                    var GroupMembers = Parse.Object.extend("GroupMembers");
                    var query1 = new Parse.Query(GroupMembers);
                    query1.equalTo("GroupId", results[i].id);
                    query1.find({
                        success: function(grpresults) {
                            for (var j = 0; j < grpresults.length; ++j) {
                                grpresults[j].set("GroupType", "Private");
                                grpresults[j].save();
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            response.error(error);
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Script is running properly(it updates the values as defined). But in parse log it shown as  Failed with: success/error was not called. Please suggest me over this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply never call `response.success()` or `response.error()`, and you should always call at least one of those.

You should really be storing all of the promises returned from your queries and saves and waiting until all of them are complete and then calling success or error based on the result from those promises.

Comment: Wain if i add success/error in 1st method the 2nd method is not working. if i add in 2nd it will again arise the log in parse, Failed with: success/error was not called.

Comment: can you help me out from tis

Comment: You're using `.then` on the queries but never doing anything with the returned promises or handling / capturing the inner promises from the saves - do you understand what the promises are for?

Comment: Hi wain now i made some changes in code. see the code posted now, then also it will arise the log in parse, Failed with: success/error was not called

Comment: Any one please guide me what is the issue in it

Comment: You need to wait for a promise at the end, or an array of them, and then call `response.success` - returning a promise is not appropriate

Comment: I see an update covering error, which looks good, but you need to cover the success case and include the `save` calls in that.

Comment: Hi wain Thaank you for your guidance, I tried using response.success , when i declare for first success it doesn't run query1 part. When i used for second success it works good for successive 2 for loops it fails for more than 2 loops. It failed to update the record

Comment: Do you understand the concept of promises and chaining? Look at https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-parallel You need to wait for everything to be complete before calling success.